# XCode 9: Setting RootViewController in AppDelegate causes black screen after launching the application

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode9

I am currently updating my application to be compatible with iOS 11.

In my app, I set the rootViewController in my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = MainViewController()
self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

In my MainViewController, I determine what VC should be the initial view controller upon launching

1. If no token exists -> Go to LoginViewController
2. If token is still valid -> Go to HomeViewController

Here is the viewDidLoad() of my MainViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // main tab bar controller
    self.initTabBarMainController()

    // login page
    self.initLoginViewController()

    // checking the session
    let tokenExpired = SessionManager.sharedInstance.isTokenExpired()
    if Utilities.isLoggedIn() && SessionManager.sharedInstance.getSessionToken() != nil && !tokenExpired 
    {
      self.addChildViewController(self.mainTabViewController!)
      self.view.addSubview((self.mainTabViewController?.view)!)
    } else {
      self.addChildViewController(self.loginViewController!)
      self.view.addSubview((self.loginViewController?.view)!)
    }

    self.setupNotifications()

  }
```

However, in iOS 11, when I try to run this. It only launches the app and stuck in black screen.

NOTES:

1. The app didn't hung, the phone didn't hung. It seems that the app doesn't load a view anymore.
2. It went to the viewDidLoad() of the correct ViewController
3. I am sure that it is the problem because when I try to remove this code and let the app go to its MainInterface after launching, there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to make it visible:

```
self.window.rootViewController = MainViewController()
self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

In the `MainViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // main tab bar controller
    self.initTabBarMainController()

    // login page
    self.initLoginViewController()

    // checking the session
    let tokenExpired = SessionManager.sharedInstance.isTokenExpired()
    var presentedViewController: UIViewController? = nil
    if Utilities.isLoggedIn() && SessionManager.sharedInstance.getSessionToken() != nil && !tokenExpired 
    {
      presentedViewController = self.mainTabViewController!
    } else {
      presentedViewController = self.loginViewController!
    }

    self.addChildViewController(presentedViewController!)
    presentedViewController!.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(presentedViewController!.view)

    self.setupNotifications()

}
```

Comment: sorry, I tried this also but it still does not solve the problem. I will edit the question to avoid confusion

Comment: did you create the window yourself or is it loaded through storyboards? + can you provide the whole `didFinishedLaunching` method implementation to give us a bit more context?

Comment: I edited my question to show the viewDidLoad of my MainViewController.
The didFinishedLaunching's relevant code is only the two lines of code you mentioned

Comment: confirm that the MainViewController gets presented correctly, either by using Capture View Hierarchy in debugger, or by setting its background color to for example red..

Comment: i just tried it now by changing the background color. it is presented correctly.
I also checked the frames of the views of LoginViewController and MainTabBarVC after initializing, and all is well.
 I'll try to see if the problem is in the code where i add the childViewController.

Comment: just adding the `self.view.addSubview((self.mainTabViewController?.view)!)` should be enough to present it to the screen.. where do you set up the constraints/frames for that added views? without setting their frames or setting up autolayout constraints I doubt those views will be presented properly (most probably they will have their size set to CGRect.zero)

Comment: they are all instantiated from their respective storyboards. I also checked their frames and they have the correct width and height of the phone screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156331/discussion-between-milan-nosa-and-ace-rivera).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Hi all, it appears it only occurs on XCode 9 emulators. I tried again today using different phones with iOS 11 version. Works fine.

---

I solved the problem by handling everything in my AppDelegate and not using a container view that will decide if loginVC will show up or the MainTabVC

1. Initialize MainTabBarVC and LoginVC  in my AppDelegate
2. setup login and logout notifications in my AppDelegate
3. handle swapping of rootViewController in my AppDelegate
4. Checkers for existing token in my AppDelegate

I will use this for now since I think there is a bug in either XCode 9 or iOS 11 that will not let me handle this in a separate ViewController where I add them as childViewController like how I do it before.

Hopefully it can be resolved soon in the best way possible.
Crowded AppDelegate is an eyesore.